# How do I change the phone number to name android?

Tags: android, arraylist

**I have this method to display the contact numbers in my inbox:**

```
    public ArrayList<String> fetchInboxNumbers() {

    ArrayList<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
    Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSms,
            new String[] { "_id", "address", "date", "body" }, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        address = cursor.getString(1); // Displays phone number


        Log.d("CONTACT", address);
        sms.add(address); // + " " + body
    }

    Log.d("NAMES IN CALLLOG", sms.get(7));

    return sms;
} // END FETCHINBOX
```

What I'm trying to do is change `String address` to its contact name.

From `fetchContactNumbers()` and 'fetchContactNames()`, how can I change`address` to a contact name?

Its important to understand that `fetchContactNumbers` and `fetchContactNames()` are aligned, meaning `fetchContactNumbers().get(5)`'s contact name is fetchContactNames().get(5)`.

In the end, `fetchInboxNumbers()` populates a custom adapter.

**This method returns a list of all contact names:**

```
public ArrayList<String> fetchContactNames() {

    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {

        String name = phones
                .getString(phones
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        names.add(name);
    }
    phones.close();

    return names;
}
```

**And this method lists all phone numbers:**

```
public ArrayList<String> fetchContactNumbers() {

    ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String phoneNumber = phones
                .getString(phones
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        numbers.add(phoneNumber);
    }
    phones.close();

    return numbers;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CONTENT_FILTER_URI` to get the display name, instead of getting all names and numbers separately, something like below:

```
public ArrayList<String> fetchInboxNumbers() {
    String displayName = "";
    ArrayList<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
    Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSms,
        new String[] { "_id", "address", "date", "body" }, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        address = cursor.getString(1); // Displays phone number
        displayName = getDisplayName(address);
        sms.add(displayName); // + " " + body
    }
    return sms;
} // END FETCHINBOX

private String getDisplayName(String phoneNumber) {
    String displayName = ""; 
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,      Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] { Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        displayName =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }
    return displayName;
}
```

Comment: This is very interesting, but how would I apply this in my fetchInboxNumbers()?

Comment: I am not sure why do you need the method `fetchInboxNumbers`, because you already have the number from `smsuri`. So, all you need is to write a method which takes `phoneNumber` as parameter and returns back the `displayName` as described above.

Comment: fetchInboxNumbers only gets a list of contact numbers who sent me an SMS message. If I can implement your method above to it, it should turn all phone numbers in my inbox into contact names. The problem I see is replacing new String[] { "_id", "address", "date", "body" } from my method with new String[] { Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME}

Comment: Sorry. I mistook `fetchInboxNumbers` for `fetchContactNumbers`. You need not replace that. Thats the standard constants for `ID` and `DISPLAY_NAME`. So, soon after you get the address, call this new method passing the address: `address = cursor.getString(1);        name = getDisplayName(address);`

Comment: what type of method is getDisplayName?

Comment: Sorry, Im not quite understanding this

Comment: Just updated the answer with more code sample. That should help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12416/discussion-between-chocoman-and-chandra)

Comment: For some reason, it doesnt like the getDisplayName(address) being called. I keep getting this: http://pastebin.com/cWng4Y2Z

Comment: As per the log it says, `NullPointerException` at `com.my.qpp.CallLog.getDisplayName(CallLog.java:322)`. Check what can be null at that line.

Comment: As @lalit pointed out, there is a spelling mistake in my code. Updated the code.

Comment: I fixed the spelling, but this line is said to be null: Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] { Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);

Comment: aa.. i see.. I was using the `context` variable. I guess you should be fine by removing that.  If not, try pass `context` value to `getDisplayName` method.

Comment: Didnt work. Got "IllegalArgumentException URI: content://com.android.contacts/phone_lookup/" for the same lines. I dont know what say, but thanks for helping this far. If anything else comes to mind, please let me know. I will most-likely be on this all week...

Comment: hm... `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown if the phonenumber you have passed is null or empty string. SO, put a condition before calling the method, `getDisplayName`.

Comment: ok I made the mistake of initializing address in getDisplayName to nothing. Now the code works!!! Thank your for your help Chandra! Now I'm off to the next problem!

Answer (score 0):

Is it a spelling mistake? a variable mistake?

```
private String getDisplayName(String phoneNyumber) {

    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.
                            CONTENT_FILTER_URI,      Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    .....
    }
```

Your argument is having `phoneNyumber` and you are using `phoneNumber`.

Comment: Yup. That's spelling mistake. Thanks.